# How do I set a bigger resolution for the Audacity frequency axis?

Tags: audacity, spectrogram

I'm analysing some spectrograms, but I want to exactly measure some maximums and minimums and I must have a bigger resolution than the automatic one.
[image]

I mean, how can I set the program to show me where is the value of 4,51 ; 4,52 ; 4,53 and so on...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd question weather it's a spectrogram that you need.

A spectrogram is more for visually analysing frequency changes *over time*.

It would be better for you to use a frequency analysis graph/spectrum analysis graph. I think it's labeled as 'Plot Spectrum' in Audacity.

Audacity is not the best for analysing in this way.

Comment: "Audacity is not the best..." do you have specific alternatives in mind?